# How to "ABORT" a function with tkinter button during a function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm newer to Python and trying to learn some best practices. Here is my current dilemma...

I've created a class `RunStart()` that is called when a button is pushed from the parent window. My goal is to have the `start_find_endpoint()` function run and to have an "ABORT" button still active that will stop the function and return to the parent frame `StartPage()`. When I run the script, my `StartPage()` is not called and the `start_find_endpoint()` function is called immediately. This is not what I want. I want the `StartPage()` frame to show up first, then call this class and run the function. All the while I want "ABORT" button to be available to be clicked and have the function terminate and go back to the StartPage frame.

```
class RunStart(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = ttk.Label(self, text='ENDPOINT SYSTEM', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        abort_button = tk.Button(self, # This "ABORT" button should be able to be pressed at any time to terminate the function and call the parent frame StartPage
                        text="ABORT", 
                        font=('century gothic', 24),
                        bg='red', 
                        fg='white', 
                        height=1,
                        width=17,
                        relief='raised',
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)
                        )
        abort_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        start_find_endpoint() # This function should start running when the frame is called.
```